# Reading object in client side written in the HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, servlets

I am uploading a file through a com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FileUpload, when the file arrives to the server I want to be able to tell the client what is the status of the upload. To this end I wrote a simple Message class that implements the java.io.Serializable interface and I write the object to the response this way:

```
outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
outputStream.writeObject(object);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

The problem is that in the client I don't know how to deserialize this object. how can I access the outputstream to reconstruct the object, I have this method:

```
form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler()
{
    public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event)
    {
       String result = event.getResults();
    });
}
```

I know I can just write a simple String into the response and set the content type to "text/plain", but I would really like to know to do it with objects. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The client is a web page?

Comment: Well, yeah, it is a web application, built with gwt.